# How to specify mime type for ServiceStack AllowFileExtensions entry?

Tags: .net, iis, servicestack

To to serve static content, like svg files, I've added extensions like this:

```cs
endpointHostConfig.AllowFileExtensions.Add("svg");
```

But ServiceStack ignores IIS mime type and usess own wrong mime type "application/svg". How to specify correct mime type, for example "image/svg+xml" for svg extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your own custom mime-types by adding it to:

```
MimeTypes.ExtensionMimeTypes["svg"] = "image/svg+xml";
```

I've also [just added the SVG mime-type to the default list of AllowedFileExtensions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/9cd3c117623d2b3afff5cf639a68dbb341022a6c) so this will be allowed by default in the next release of ServiceStack v3.9.44+.

Comment: Thanks. I was simpy using outdated version without MimeTypes field. Adding those to support webfonts will be nice: { "eot", "application/vnd.ms-fontobject" }, { "ttf", "application/octet-stream" }, { "woff", "application/font-woff" }.

Comment: @Savvkin Done. Added in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/94d75d85d02d0b65de521f5cb8afc959f6a1b367).